# Salvaging diverged neural networks

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I have a DCNN that diverged after several epochs of training, but which had good results initially. Is it "safe" to go back an epoch, or fraction of an epoch, lower the learning rate, and continue, or should I assume some weights may be close to being ill-conditioned and hence it's necessary to completely restart the training (with lowered learning rates)?

A related question is what kind of behavior internal to the network produces such a result. I thought divergence should happen very early in training, not when the network already seems close to full convergence.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. It's not safe because if the divergence was caused by a large learning rate, it would most possibly had happened at the beginning epoch. Some weights may have already been ill-conditioned.
2. In general, the result is mainly caused by gradient errors. Gradient errors may come from:

   **Error of forward and backword calculation of some layer in your DCNN:**
   Both error in forward and backward  calculation may result in wrong gradient for model parameters's updating, although it may not cause the divergence at the beginning but it can update some parameters in the wrong way and accumulate till these parameters become ill-conditioned enough to cause the training divergence.

   **Numerical instability**: For example, when you calculate the variance D(X) of X, D(X)=E{[X - E(X)]^2} has more numerical instability than D(X) = E(X^2) - E^2(X) because the last one may result in a negative D(X) and thus cause gradient errors even divergence.

Comment: Good point for (1). I dumped the weights to a file (for the "go back and lower" network) and looked for high absolute values, and didn't find any. So I guess I'm good there. As for (2), I'm using Caffe+cUDNN, so there hopefully shouldn't be errors in the gradient calculation, but I'm not so sure about the numerical stability.

Comment: Did you use Sigmoid as activation fuction or can you upload your net. prototxt? @gcp

Comment: I was using ELU, though that may be a bit similar to sigmoid in the negative zone? It's a standard pure convolutional network, i.e. a stack of convolution->ELU->convolution->ELU->etc.

Comment: If you had performed "make runtest" after building caffe and no errors  were casted, the last problem  I can think of  may be the large learning rate, which means you'd better restart the training with lowered learning rates. @gcp

Comment: Have you find out the problem? @gcp

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Caffe works fine. The divergence is "caused" by the large learning rate. This was already stated in the original question. I'm none the wiser as to what causes divergence after several epochs of convergence. My best best is that the training data has a minibatch with an unfortunate grouping of some outliers/unusual cases that caused a huge gradient swing. Those would have larger gradients after training/convergence than before.

Comment: What I was asking for is what's the reason of the divergence after several epochs you find out. By the way, what's exactly the process of the divergence after several epochs you mentioned?@gcp

Comment: The training and testing errors jump from a very small value to a very large one (similar to completely untrained network). It does not gradually get worse, it's extremely fast.

Comment: @gcp I still suspect that there is numerical instability. Would changing `ELU` to `ReLU` help?